# c++ templates to represent polynomials

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, template-specialization

I am trying to use templates to represent simple polynomials like x^2 + 3x + 5. My idea is to represent them as sum of terms with each term having a coefficient and a power so e.g. x^2 has coeff=1 and power=2. I also want to be able to evaluate the polynomials for some x (they only have 1 unknown but in many places). So far I have:

```
struct PolyEnd{
    double eval(double x){
        return 0;
    }
};

template <int coeff, int power, class Tail> struct Poly {
    typedef Tail tt;

    double eval(double x){
        double curr = coeff * std::pow(x, power);
        return curr; // has to call eval(x) on rest of the terms which are in the tail and return the sum with "curr"
    }
};

int main()
{
    double x = 2;
    Poly<1,1,Poly<1,1,PolyEnd>> poly;
    std::cout << poly.eval(x) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, I am stuck. Is what I am trying even possible? If so how can I make the recursive eval() calls work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, you just need to call `eval` on the tail and since all the classes are state-less, you can just create an instance to call the member function on, on the spot:

```
struct PolyEnd{
    double eval(double x){
        return 0;
    }
};

template <int coeff, int power, class Tail> struct Poly {
    typedef Tail tt;

    double eval(double x){
        double curr = coeff * std::pow(x, power);
        return curr + Tail{}.eval(x);
    }
};

int main()
{
    double x = 2;
    Poly<1,1,Poly<1,1,PolyEnd>> poly;
    std::cout << poly.eval(x) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

or if you make `eval` `static`, then you can call `Tail::eval(x)` directly.

Comment: Thanks! One more thing - how could I represent (x-2)^2? Any ideas?

Comment: @Parankush I am not sure why you are doing this in the first place. Something like this is usually only useful if you intend to do transformations on the polynomial at compile-time, e.g. for *expression templates*. How it would make sense to represent, parse and do transformations on the polynomials is then up to you and your specific use case.

Comment: @Parankush: That's not a polynomial, so you need something entirely different and _way_ more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you are experimenting with **metaprogramming**. Your question also made me excited, because i am also newbie in metaprogramming and I want to practise. @walnut's answer already accepted but there is no harm to share another implementation. I used some basic metaprogramming techniques.

I hope it will help you.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<int Value>
struct coeff
{   };

template<int Value>
struct power
{   };

template<typename Coefficient, typename Power>
struct term;

template<int Coefficient , int Power>
struct term< coeff<Coefficient> , power<Power> >
{
    inline double eval( double  x ) const noexcept { 
        return Coefficient * std::pow( x , Power );
    }
};

template<int Value>
using constant = term< coeff<Value> , power<1> >;

template<int Value>
using exponential = term< coeff<1> , power<Value> >;

template<typename... T>
struct polynomial
{

    static_assert( sizeof...(T) == 0, "A polynomial can only be expressed in 'term's.");

    [[nodiscard]] constexpr double eval( double ) const noexcept {
        return 0;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] std::string to_string() const noexcept {
        return std::string{};
    }
};

template<int Coefficient, int Power, typename... Tail>
struct polynomial<term< coeff<Coefficient> , power<Power> >, Tail...>
       :   polynomial<Tail...>
{
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr double eval( double x ) const noexcept {
        return m_t.eval( x ) + polynomial<Tail...>::eval( x );
    }

    [[nodiscard]] std::string to_string(){
        using namespace std;
        using namespace std::string_literals;
        return "("s + std::to_string( Coefficient ) + 
               string { "x^" } +
               std::to_string( Power ) + ( sizeof...(Tail) == 0 ? ")" : ") + " ) + 
               polynomial<Tail...>::to_string();
    }

    private:

        term< coeff<Coefficient> , power<Power> > m_t;

};

int main()
{
    auto p1 = polynomial<term< coeff<1> , power<2> > ,
                         term< coeff<2> , power<4> > ,
                         term< coeff<2> , power<3> > ,
                         constant<3> ,
                         exponential<2> >{};

    std::cout << "Polynomial is : " << p1.to_string() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "f(2) : " << p1.eval( 2 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "f(3) : " << p1.eval( 3 ) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[run online](https://repl.it/repls/WigglyCloudyComma)

Answer (score 1):

Polynomial coefficients can be stored in `std::array` or `std::vector`(in case you define polynomial degree in runtime).

Then extend functionality with `eval` function.

```
template <unsigned N>
class Poly : public std::array<double, N> {
public:
  template <typename... E>
  Poly(E &&... e) : std::array<double, N>{{std::forward<E>(e)...}} {}

  double eval(double x) {
    double result = 0;
    double exp = 1.;
    for (auto it = this->rbegin(); it != this->rend(); ++it) {
      result += exp * (*it);
      exp *= x;
    }
    return result;
  }
};
```

usage

```
double result = Poly<3>{3., 2., 1.}.eval(17);
```